# In Xcode, NSFetchRequest is only returning the Objects, but not their attributes

Tags: ios, xcode, core-data, nsfetchrequest

I have the following code to fetch a set of 'Projects' from the core data (each 'Project' has some attributes, e.g. 'title','time','endTime','pay' etc.):

```
NSFetchRequest *request = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
    NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"Project" inManagedObjectContext:__managedObjectContext];
    [request setEntity:entity];

    NSSortDescriptor *sortDescriptor = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"endTime" ascending:NO];
    NSArray *sortDescriptors = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:sortDescriptor, nil];
    [request setSortDescriptors:sortDescriptors];


    NSError *error = nil;
    NSMutableArray *mutableFetchResults = [[__managedObjectContext executeFetchRequest:request error:&error] mutableCopy];
    if (mutableFetchResults == nil) {
        // Handle the error.
    }

    [self setEventsArray:mutableFetchResults];
```

However only the Projects are returned not their attributes :`<NSManagedObject: 0x154010> (entity: Project; id: 0x1dad70 <x-coredata://85BD9DF1-B41B-4234-8397-C2F568D0CC7A/Project/p3> ; data: <fault>`

Do I have to fetch the attributes separately or have i missed something? thanks.

Comment: What is the lifecycle of your __managedObjectContext? Are you possibly using ARC so that the NSManagedContext gets dealloced after calling it the 2. time?

Answer (score 2):

It's normal to see a fault with a fetch. Faults are stand ins or "ghost" objects that represent a managed object's place in the object graph without the overhead of loading a bunch of attribute data that may never be needed.

You won't see the log of attributes until you try to access one of the attributes of a particular managed object.

Newly created objects or changes to attributes of existing objects will not be saved to disk until you call save on the managed object context.

Answer (score 1):

`data: <fault>` simply means that the attributes haven't been loaded **yet**. As soon as you access on the attributes, it will be retrieved from the database.

Comment: ohh, ok but then why does it not load the attributes i had saved on the last session i used: `NSManagedObject *object = [self detailItem];
    [object setValue:self.title forKey:@"title"];` to save them, they should load into labels btw

Comment: Are you sure that they're not loaded? Try printing on of those attributes specifically, rather than printing the whole object.

Comment: i have the are printed on labels & text fields but it loads the data i entered when i originally created the project not the edited values

Comment: Did you call `save` on your MOC?

Comment: Thank you so much, yes that was it... you saved me a lot of bother.

Comment: Hi, for some weird reason it has stopped working, i haven't touched the code since, just been to the shops, came back tried it again and it has started doing what it was doing before?